# Wake up from screen off (like Windows and Mac)

Tags: touchpad, screen, lock-screen, lock

Is there a way to configure Ubuntu such that it doesn't require 2 keystrokes to wake it up from the state where the screen is disabled after being absent, but a simple touch on the touchpad suffices (akin to the behavior of Windows and MacOS)?

Comment: When I lock the screen, or suspend the device, my system wakes with one keystroke (I press shift) and displays the password dialog box. I enter my password and press enter and I'm off. Can you provide more information so I can better understand what is happening for you?

Comment: Hm, which distribution do you run? On Ubuntu (and the Ubuntu based elementaryOS Luna that I'm running now), I have to press a key once to turn on the screen, but have it black with the time at the top, and then once more and the background image appears and the password dialog. For me it just really makes no sense why it takes two steps and not one.

Comment: standard Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `synaptiks`

From command line open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command :

```
sudo apt-get install synaptiks
```

Or from Ubuntu Software Center search for the keyword `synaptiks`

Comment: I was looking for something like this, so thanks. But how does this show the lockscreen with one keypress or touch of the touchpad?